# Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page not caching (did not work)

Tags: php, zend-framework

Good day,

I have run into some problem in the Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page. I want to use Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page to caching some of pages. But it does not work.

```
protected function _initBookPageCaching()
{
    Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setParam('disableOutputBuffering',true);      
    // cache book pages
    $frontendOptionsPages = array(
       'lifetime' => 2592000,
       'debug_header' => true, // for debugging
       'regexps' => array(
           // cache the whole IndexController
           '^/$' => array('cache' => true),
           '^/download-free-ebook/.*' => array('cache' => true)
       )
    );

    $backendOptionsPages = array(
        'cache_dir' =>  APPLICATION_PATH.'/../cache'
    );

    $cacheBookPages = Zend_Cache::factory(
                         'Page',
                         'File',
                         $frontendOptionsPages,
                         $backendOptionsPages);

    $cacheBookPages->start();
}
```

i set above method into Bootstrap.php file.

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Is it creating a file in your cache directory? This will tell us if the cache is even being _created_ in the first place, let alone being used.

Comment: no it does not create any file

Comment: Ok gotcha, what is APPLICATION_PATH set to? Try `echo APPLICATION_PATH . '/../cache';` and show me the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never actually use Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance() in my bootstrap, rather I use:

```
$this->bootstrap('frontController');
```

followed by:

```
$front = $this->getResource('frontController');
```

with which you could try:

```
$front->setParam('disableOutputBuffering', true);
```

Also, I'm not sure what the acceptable regex's are for controllers and what not. Maybe try changing `'^/download-free-ebook/.*'` to `'^/download-free-ebook/'`.  And see if just the index action for that controller at least caches.

**EDIT:**
I found the issue. $cache->start(); is returning false so I did some debugging. You're not passing a cache id (e.g. `$cacheBookPages->start('some_cache_id');`) so Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page attempts to make one for you on line 261. like so:

```
// from Zend/Cache/Frontend/Page.php
public function start($id = false, $doNotDie = false)
{
    // ....
    if (!$id) {
        $id = $this->_makeId();
        if (!$id) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // ....
}
```

So after following the rabbit trail, I realized that it was trying to build a cache id based off the following arrays: $_GET, $_POST, $_SESSION, $_COOKIE and $_FILES.  Since none of those are set it is unable to create a cache id! And since it can't create a cache id, it can't create the cache file.

Solution:

```
$uri      = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$cacheKey = array();
foreach ($uri as $key) {
    if (empty($key)) {
        continue 1;
    }
    $cacheKey[] = $key;
}

$cacheBookPages->start('page_cache_' . implode('_', $cacheKey));
```

Comment: i have checked this changes but did not help. the URL is "/download-free-ebook/landscape-ecology" and this regex '^/download-free-ebook/.*' is works.

Comment: read my edit. I tried this very same code on mine and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

**Set application.ini**

```
 resources.frontController.params.disableOutputBuffering = true
```

**set bootstrap or action**

```
$frontendOptions = array(
        'lifetime' => 900,
        'automatic_serialization' => true,
        'default_options' => array(
            'cache_with_get_variables' => true,
            'cache_with_post_variables' => true,
            'cache_with_session_variables' => true,
            'cache_with_files_variables' => true,
            'cache_with_cookie_variables' => true,
            'make_id_with_get_variables' => true,
            'make_id_with_post_variables' => true,
            'make_id_with_session_variables' => true,
            'make_id_with_files_variables' => true,
            'make_id_with_cookie_variables' => true,
            'cache'=>true
        ),


    );

    $backendOptions = array(
        'cache_dir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/servercache/'
    );
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Page', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
    $cache->start();
```

And here we go!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, regex may be wrong, especially slash may cause problems. Try to escape it by puting \ before each slash and if this not work, try to put everything in slashes like:
'/^/download-free-ebook/.*/'

Comment: the URL is "/download-free-ebook/landscape-ecology" and this regex '^/download-free-ebook/.*' is works.